# How to move a rectangle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, replit

I'm trying to make a moving rectangle in Pygame. I understand that I first need to use pygame.draw.rect(), in which I have. I am using an online IDE temporarily, Repl.it. I just need to make sure that this code is correct.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
x = 500
y = 300
white = (255,255,255)
player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x,y,50,40))

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if pygame.event == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.QUIT
      sys.exit()
    if pygame.event == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if pygame.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x -= 5
      if pygame.event == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x += 5
  pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is *close* to working.

There's a few places you're checking the wrong part of the event, mostly you have the same mistake in multiple places.

Also you're not re-drawing the rectangle when the co-ordinates change.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
x = 500
y = 300
black = (  0,  0,  0)
white = (255,255,255)

while True:
    # Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:            # <<-- HERE use event.type
            pygame.quit()                        # <<-- HERE use pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:       # <<-- HERE use event.type
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:       # <<-- HERE use event.key
                x -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:    # <<-- HERE use event.key
                x += 5

    # Reapint the screen
    screen.fill( black )                                     # erase old rectangle
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x,y,50,40))    # draw new rectangle
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I have made the changes and pygame.event the same. And it still does not work

Comment: Nevermind. Needed to change pygame.event to event.type. Thanks :)